# ListView with black colored containers shows a 1 px white line between them

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Listview Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ListWidget({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width: width,
          height: height,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        Container(
          width: width,
          height: height,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        Container(
          width: width,
          height: height,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        Container(
          width: width,
          height: height,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

When I run the above code in emulator, sometimes there is a thin white line appearing between two containers as shown below.

[image: White line between two black containers]

This happens almost always and is much more noticeable when I build the app for the web and runs on chrome.
Even the production build has these lines.

[image]

I am unable to figure out what is happening, I even tried replacing ListView with a SingleChildScrollView with child as a Column. But its still the same.

Comment: I tried the same code in my demo project and there is no white lines between these containers.

Comment: @DhavalKansara Are you running it on chrome?